# How do deal with "+" signs in Email for Unsubscription

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Below URL we are using as Un-subscription link in our Exact Target email template. It's working perfectly fine; until someone have "+" sign in Email then user sees an error page.

```
http://pages.abc.com/page.aspx?QS=12345&email=%%Email%%&corporation=%%Corporation%%&recordtype=%%RecordType%%
```

When I manually replace "+" sign with '%2b' in URL then it works.

Is there a way I can encode/decode or replace Emails with plus sign in URL? I tried URLEncode function but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd opt for using the Base64 encode/decode functions, so you're not passing [**PII**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information) around in the URLs.

**Email**

```
%%[
SET @email = AttributeValue("Email")
SET @email = Base64Encode(@Email)
]%%
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(ConCat('http://example.com/page.aspx?QS=12345&e=',@email))=%%">link</a>
```

**Landing Page**

```
%%[
SET @email = QueryParameter("e")
set @email = Base64Decode(@Email,"UTF-8")
]%%
<br>Email: %%=v(@email)=%%
```

**Reference**

- [**Base64Encode()**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/base64encode/) function
- [**Base64Decode()**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/base64decode/) function

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Replace AmpScript](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/string/Replace.html) function to replace  emailaddress '+' sign to any other special characters something like below.

**Email Code:**

```
%%[
SET @Corporation = AttributeValue("Corporation")
SET @RecordType = AttributeValue("RecordType")
SET @Email = AttributeValue("Email")
SET @Email = Replace(@Email,'+','*')
]%%

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p><a href="%%=RedirectTo(ConCat('http://pages.abc.com/page.aspx?QS=12345&email=',@Email,'&corporation=',@Corporation,'&recordtype=',@RecordType))=%%">Unsubscribe</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**LandingPage Code:**

```
%%[
SET @Email = QueryParameter("email")
SET @Email = Replace(@Email,'*','+')
]%%

%%=v(@Email)=%%
```